# Running a haml file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a rails app, that has a haml file in the view.  I would like to see the haml file in the browser, what is the correct way of doing this?

I have started up `rails s`

using `http://localhost:3000`

but how do I view the haml file by it self?

Comment: Do you want to see the Haml source or the HTML that was rendered by Haml?

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and show us the output

Comment: the html that was rendered by the haml, I want to see it in the browser.

Comment: @Charles /users/home#navigation

Comment: No, please give us the whole ouput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haml is just another template language like ERb, so you can treat it exactly the same as a view written in ERb:

1. Create a route.
2. Create a controller with an action for that route.
3. Create a view for the controller action.
4. Visit the URL corresponding to the route.